# Bypassing development profile for using Instruments on jailbroken phone

Tags: ios, jailbreak, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

Instruments tool available in Xcode, it allows to test the applications for which we have development profile. I am using jailbroken device, and also I am not using development provisioning profile. I want to use UI Automation tool of Instruments to test my app.

Is there any way by using which I can bypass the development profile and can test my application on device using `UIAutomation` of Instruments.

Comment: I am also interested in finding this out. UIAutomation looks like a great tool but it is too dependent on Instruments. I want to run the script headless.

Comment: Did you find answer to your question?